# error Axis2 client invoke SSL Service from J2EE application in Websphere6.1

Tags: ssl, client, websphere, apache-axis

I am stucked in the issue where my axis2 based client call the ssl service from websphere 6.1 and throws the following exception along with the message at the top. I have followed the step from [click here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/download/attachments/116424904/basic_ssl_cert_exchange_1109.pdf?version=1) to install the ssl certificate using IBM websphere admin console in default trust store. Please note this client was working fine for APACHE tomcat. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciable Thanks.

```
setting up default SSLSocketFactory

class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory is loaded

SSLSocketFactory instantiation failed: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory incompatible with         javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory

{HttpMethodDirector:439} - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when     processing request: java.lang.ClassCastException:     com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory 
incompatible with javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory

{HttpMethodDirector:445} - Retrying request

{HttpMethodDirector:439} - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when     processing request: java.lang.ClassCastException:     com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory incompatible with     javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory

{HttpMethodDirector:445} - Retrying request

{HttpMethodDirector:439} - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when     processing request: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory incompatible with javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory

{HttpMethodDirector:445} - Retrying request

{HTTPSender:202} - Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://sma/CBDSMS/api/GetDue.svc]
java.net.SocketException: java.lang.ClassCastException:     com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory incompatible with     javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.throwException(Unknown Source)
at javax.net.ssl.DefaultSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:130)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:560)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:438)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

Answer (score 0):

please user "parent last" setting in the classloader for this web app. see [here](http://websphereapplicationservernotes.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/classnotfound-a-close-look-at-class-loader-in-websphere-application-server/) for details.

Comment: Thanks for showing interest Davanum, are you talking about module classloader its already set to application class loader first, as without doing this application was not even starting...